# Multiple separate joins in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 and have problem with multiple joins. I have two tables - one with customers and the other one with means to communicate with them. Here's a simple design:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Communication (
    id_customer INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Customers(id),
    type CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

To make it simple, `Communication.type` column has either a letter 'T' for a phone number or 'E' for an e-mail address. Here are some simple values:

```
INSERT INTO Customers(id, name) VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'Patrick'), (3, 'Bill');

INSERT INTO Communication(id_customer, type, content) VALUES
    (1, 'T', '666 555 444'),
    (1, 'E', 'john@aa.com'),
    (1, 'E', 'doe@aa.com'),

    (2, 'T', '123456789'),
    (2, 'T', '987654321'),
    (2, 'T', '111111111'),
    (2, 'E', 'patrick@aa.com'),

    (3, 'T', '190'),
    (3, 'T', '90');
```

Now I want to list all customers with all their e-mails and phone numbers in a form of a PostgreSQL array. I went with the following query at first:

```
SELECT id, name, array_agg(phone.content), array_agg(email.content) FROM Customers
    LEFT JOIN Communication AS phone ON phone.type = 'T' AND phone.id_customer = id
    LEFT JOIN Communication AS email ON email.type = 'E' AND email.id_customer = id
    GROUP BY id;
```

Here's the result:

```
 id |  name   |            array_agg            |                   array_agg
----+---------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------
  1 | John    | {"666 555 444","666 555 444"}   | {john@aa.com,doe@aa.com}
  2 | Patrick | {123456789,987654321,111111111} | {patrick@aa.com,patrick@aa.com,patrick@aa.com}
  3 | Bill    | {190,90}                        | {NULL,NULL}
```

The most important problem is that PostgreSQL for some reason decides to force the same length of both arrays, expanding the shorter one if needed. As an effect, it duplicates the last element of the shorter array to fit the length of the longer one. Why is that so? How can I prevent this from happening?

Here's a sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28420/1

On a side note - I deliberately inserted a phone number with spaces. Turns out the quotes are skipped, if the string can be represented as a number (even though in table definition I explicitly declared it `TEXT`). Could I possibly disable this behavior and make quotes appear at all times? They're strings after all, and I have to properly parse it afterwards. The easier the better.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move one of the aggregations to an outer query:

```
SELECT id, name, phones, array_agg(email.content)
FROM (  
    SELECT 
        id, name, array_agg(phone.content) phones
    FROM Customers
    LEFT JOIN Communication AS phone 
        ON phone.type = 'T' AND phone.id_customer = id
    GROUP BY 1
    ) phone
    LEFT JOIN Communication AS email 
        ON email.type = 'E' AND email.id_customer = id
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28420/2).

However, it may be simpler with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, 
    array_agg(DISTINCT phone.content), 
    array_agg(DISTINCT email.content) 
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Communication AS phone 
    ON phone.type = 'T' AND phone.id_customer = id
LEFT JOIN Communication AS email 
    ON email.type = 'E' AND email.id_customer = id
GROUP BY id;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0793/2).

Both the above queries are fine but this one I like the best (Postgres 9.4+):

```
SELECT 
    id, name, 
    array_agg(content) FILTER (WHERE type = 'T') phone,
    array_agg(content) FILTER (WHERE type = 'E') email
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Communication ON id_customer = id
GROUP BY id;
```

Note, that you can define an order of the aggregated values, e.g.:

```
array_agg(content ORDER BY content) FILTER (WHERE type = 'T') phone
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using subqueries, but I guess I'll have to use it when if I don't find anything better. Also I'd like to know why PostgreSQL behaves like this when using multiple joins. I flicked through the PostgreSQL docs and found nothing interesting. Or maybe it's a part of SQL standard?

Comment: This is not a feature of Postgres [MySql Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/284201/4).
There is no reason to be afraid of subqueries.

Comment: @Tomalla: technically those aren't subqueries. The correct technical term for the above is a derived table. But I agree with Klin: there is no reason to not use them. The myth that sub-queries (or derived tables) are slow stems from MySQL's bad query optimizer. But in nearly every other DBMS there is no reason to avoid them "just because".

Comment: @Tomalla - Your intuition was correct. I rummaged in some of my older projects and found a simpler solution. Human memory is fallible.

Comment: Exactly, when having some duplicate data in a query result, you should use the "DISTINC" anotation. However you must be cautious with it, and know how to use it. In some cases, the DISTINCT anotation can not give you all the data you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you @ klin, the final solution is nice, tidy and works as expected. @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for getting it straight. I've decided to test these two solutions out and benchmarked them for a brief period of time. As expected the query with a derived table performed longer, though slightly. But I'm planning to run some longer tests to see how it behaves in longer runs, out of pure curiosity. Cheers

Comment: @Fares, would you mind giving some examples of such behavior?